# Reverse for 'places' with arguments '('l', 'o', 'n', 'd', 'o', 'n')' and keyword arguments '{}' not found

Tags: django, django-generic-views

**Django 1.9.6**

Could you help me understand what I'm doing wrongly.
The program tried: ['places/$']. Well, this is a bit confusing.

/places/ + argument 'london' works. I mean http://localhost:8000/places/london/ works correctly.

I would be greatfull for a kick here. Thank you in advance.

**/photoarchive/place/views.py**

```
class PlaceUpdateView(UpdateView):
    model = Place
    fields = ['modern_name', 'since', 'postal_code']
    template_name_suffix = '_update_form'
```

**/photoarchive/photoarchive/urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^places/create$', login_required(PlaceCreateView.as_view()), name="place_create"),
    url(r'^places/(?P<slug>[\w-]+)/edit$', login_required(PlaceUpdateView.as_view()), name="place_edit"),
    url(r'^places/(?P<slug>[\w-]+)/$', login_required(PlaceDetailView.as_view()), name="place"),
    url(r'^places/$', login_required(PlaceListView.as_view()), name="places"),
]
```

**/photoarchive/place/templates/place/place_update_form.html**

```
<form action="" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <input type="submit" value="Save" />
</form>
```

**Traceback**

```
Exception Type: NoReverseMatch at /places/london/edit
Exception Value: Reverse for 'places' with arguments '('l', 'o', 'n', 'd', 'o', 'n')' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['places/$']
```

**ADDED LATER (full traceback)**

```
Environment:


Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://localhost:8000/places/london/edit

Django Version: 1.9.6
Python Version: 3.5.1
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'registration',
 'homepage',
 'person',
 'general',
 'picture',
 'place']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']



Traceback:

File "/home/michael/workspace/venvs/photoarchive/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  149.                     response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "/home/michael/workspace/venvs/photoarchive/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  147.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "/home/michael/workspace/venvs/photoarchive/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  23.                 return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/home/michael/workspace/venvs/photoarchive/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py" in view
  68.             return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/home/michael/workspace/venvs/photoarchive/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py" in dispatch
  88.         return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/home/michael/workspace/venvs/photoarchive/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/views/generic/edit.py" in post
  279.         return super(BaseUpdateView, self).post(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/home/michael/workspace/venvs/photoarchive/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/views/generic/edit.py" in post
  222.             return self.form_valid(form)

File "/home/michael/workspace/venvs/photoarchive/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/views/generic/edit.py" in form_valid
  202.         return super(ModelFormMixin, self).form_valid(form)

File "/home/michael/workspace/venvs/photoarchive/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/views/generic/edit.py" in form_valid
  108.         return HttpResponseRedirect(self.get_success_url())

File "/home/michael/workspace/venvs/photoarchive/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/views/generic/edit.py" in get_success_url
  190.                 url = self.object.get_absolute_url()

File "/home/michael/workspace/venvs/photoarchive/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/__init__.py" in inner
  43.         return reverse(bits[0], None, *bits[1:3])

File "/home/michael/workspace/venvs/photoarchive/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in reverse
  600.     return force_text(iri_to_uri(resolver._reverse_with_prefix(view, prefix, *args, **kwargs)))

File "/home/michael/workspace/venvs/photoarchive/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in _reverse_with_prefix
  508.                              (lookup_view_s, args, kwargs, len(patterns), patterns))

Exception Type: NoReverseMatch at /places/london/edit
Exception Value: Reverse for 'places' with arguments '('l', 'o', 'n', 'd', 'o', 'n')' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['places/$']
```

**ADDED EVEN LATER**

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', login_required(HomePage.as_view()), name='home'),
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^accounts/logout/$', auth_views.logout, {'next_page': 'auth_login'}, name='auth_logout'),    
    url(r'^accounts/', include('registration.backends.hmac.urls')), # django-registration
    url(r'^people/create/$', login_required(PersonCreateView.as_view()), name="person_create"),
    url(r'^people/(?P<slug>[\w-]+)/edit$', login_required(PersonUpdateView.as_view()), name="person_edit"),
    url(r'^people/(?P<slug>[\w-]+)/$', login_required(PersonDetailView.as_view()), name="person"),
    url(r'^people/$', login_required(PersonListView.as_view()), name="people"),
    url(r'^search/$', login_required(SearchEngineView.as_view()), name="search"),
    url(r'^places/create$', login_required(PlaceCreateView.as_view()), name="place_create"),
    url(r'^places/(?P<slug>[\w-]+)/edit$', login_required(PlaceUpdateView.as_view()), name="place_edit"),
    url(r'^places/(?P<slug>[\w-]+)/$', login_required(PlaceDetailView.as_view()), name="place"),
    url(r'^places/$', login_required(PlaceListView.as_view()), name="places"),
]
```

**GET_ABSOLUTE_URL**

```
@models.permalink
def get_absolute_url(self):
    return ('places', self.slug)
```

**NEW EXCEPTION**

```
Environment:


Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://localhost:8000/places/london/edit

Django Version: 1.9.6
Python Version: 3.5.1
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'registration',
 'homepage',
 'person',
 'general',
 'picture',
 'place']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']



Traceback:

File "/home/michael/workspace/venvs/photoarchive/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  149.                     response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "/home/michael/workspace/venvs/photoarchive/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  147.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "/home/michael/workspace/venvs/photoarchive/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  23.                 return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/home/michael/workspace/venvs/photoarchive/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py" in view
  68.             return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/home/michael/workspace/venvs/photoarchive/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py" in dispatch
  88.         return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/home/michael/workspace/venvs/photoarchive/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/views/generic/edit.py" in post
  279.         return super(BaseUpdateView, self).post(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/home/michael/workspace/venvs/photoarchive/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/views/generic/edit.py" in post
  222.             return self.form_valid(form)

File "/home/michael/workspace/venvs/photoarchive/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/views/generic/edit.py" in form_valid
  202.         return super(ModelFormMixin, self).form_valid(form)

File "/home/michael/workspace/venvs/photoarchive/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/views/generic/edit.py" in form_valid
  108.         return HttpResponseRedirect(self.get_success_url())

File "/home/michael/workspace/venvs/photoarchive/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/views/generic/edit.py" in get_success_url
  190.                 url = self.object.get_absolute_url()

File "/home/michael/workspace/venvs/photoarchive/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/__init__.py" in inner
  43.         return reverse(bits[0], None, *bits[1:3])

File "/home/michael/workspace/venvs/photoarchive/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in reverse
  600.     return force_text(iri_to_uri(resolver._reverse_with_prefix(view, prefix, *args, **kwargs)))

File "/home/michael/workspace/venvs/photoarchive/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in _reverse_with_prefix
  508.                              (lookup_view_s, args, kwargs, len(patterns), patterns))

Exception Type: NoReverseMatch at /places/london/edit
Exception Value: Reverse for 'place' with arguments '('l', 'o', 'n', 'd', 'o', 'n')' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['places/(?P<slug>[\\w-]+)/$']
```

Comment: Can you show the full traceback?

Comment: Sayse, please, have a look.

Comment: On the `place_edit` page, you have likely a link to `places` with an argument "london", but the reverse for `places` doesn't take any arguments. You probably meant to call `url 'place'` with argument "london" instead.

Comment: C14L, you mean in html? I have shown the html. Doublechecked now: it is the very template that is rendered.

Comment: Do you have a base urls? It isn't trying to match any of the other urls which probably means its not including these urls correctly.

Comment: The traceback shows that the problem is coming from your model's `get_absolute_url` method (which is being called from the view's `get_success_url`). Please show that method, and preferably the full model code.

Comment: Sayse, to the initial at the end I have added the whole urlpatterns. No base urls.

Comment: Daniel Roseman, added to the end of the initial comment. Well, I have tried interactively. In the browser get_absolute_url() seems to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your model's `get_absolute_url` has two issues:

```
@models.permalink
def get_absolute_url(self):
    return ('places', self.slug)
```

should be

```
@models.permalink
def get_absolute_url(self):
    return ('place', (self.slug,))
```

**EDIT** I believe the second member of the tuple is supposed to be an enumerable of arguments.

**EDIT2** FYI, I believe this is preferred over using `models.permalink`:

```
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
...
def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse('place', args=(self.slug,))
```

Comment: Progress, thank you. But now it shows NoReverseMatch again: 1 pattern(s) tried: ['places/(?P<slug>[\\w-]+)/$'] The doubleslash seems to be the trouble here. Could you be so kind as to help me with it?

Comment: @Michael could you share the details of the new exception?

Comment: Thank you for you assistance. Added to the end.

Comment: Not working. .../python3.5/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 600, in reverse
    return force_text(iri_to_uri(resolver._reverse_with_prefix(view, prefix, *args, **kwargs)))
  File "/home/michael/workspace/venvs/photoarchive/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 508, in _reverse_with_prefix
    (lookup_view_s, args, kwargs, len(patterns), patterns))
django.core.urlresolvers.NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'place' with arguments '('l', 'o', 'n', 'd', 'o', 'n')' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['places/(?P<slug>[\\w-]+)/$']

Comment: smarx, thank you. This seems to be a bit another problem. I'll try to solve it separately.